# Pandas dataframe row operation with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, group-by

I have a dataframe with information about a stock that looks like this:

| Product ID | Initial stock | Initial unit cost | Reference | Quantity | Unit cost | Current stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | 22 | Purch. | 4 | 24 | 9 |
| a | 5 | 22 | Purch. | 8 | 21 | 17 |
| a | 5 | 22 | Sale | -4 | 25 | 13 |
| a | 5 | 22 | Purch. | 10 | 20 | 23 |
| a | 5 | 22 | Sale | -15 | 22 | 8 |
| b | 14 | 3.5 | Sale | 10 | 4 | 4 |
| b | 14 | 3.5 | Purch. | 20 | 3 | 24 |
| b | 14 | 3.5 | Sale | 5 | 4 | 19 |
| b | 14 | 3.5 | Purch. | 2 | 3.5 | 21 |
| c | 27 | 1 | Purch. | 100 | 0.95 | 127 |
| c | 27 | 1 | Purch. | 3 | 1.1 | 130 |

Each row represents a purchase/sale of a certain product. `Quantity` represents the number of units purchased/sold at a given `Unit cost`. `Current stock` is the remaining stock after the purchase/sale. For every product, I want to calculate the Weighted Average Cost (WAC) after each sale/purchase. The procedure is the following:

- For the first row of every product, `WAC = (Initial stock * Initial unit cost + Quantity * Unit cost) / Current stock` just if `Reference == 'Purch.'`. If not, `WAC = Initial unit cost`.
- For the next rows, `WAC[i] = (Current stock[i-1] * WAC[i-1] + Quantity[i] * Unit cost[i]) / Current stock[i]` just if `Reference[i] == 'Purch.'`. If not, `WAC[i] = WAC[i-1]`.

The next table shows what I'm looking for (`WAC` column and how to calculate it):

| Product ID | Initial stock | Initial unit cost | Reference | Quantity | Unit cost | Current stock | (how to) WAC | WAC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | 22 | Purch. | 4 | 24 | 9 | (5*22 + 4*24)/9 | 22.89 |
| a | 5 | 22 | Purch. | 8 | 21 | 17 | (9*22.89 + 8*21)/17 | 22 |
| a | 5 | 22 | Sale | -4 | 25 | 13 | - | 22 |
| a | 5 | 22 | Purch. | 10 | 20 | 23 | (13*22 + 10*20)/23 | 21.13 |
| a | 5 | 22 | Sale | -15 | 22 | 8 | - | 21.13 |
| b | 14 | 3.5 | Sale | 10 | 4 | 4 | - | 3.5 |
| b | 14 | 3.5 | Purch. | 20 | 3 | 24 | (4*3.5 + 20*3)/24 | 3.08 |
| b | 14 | 3.5 | Sale | 5 | 4 | 19 | - | 3.08 |
| b | 14 | 3.5 | Purch. | 2 | 3.5 | 21 | (19*3.08 + 2*3.5)/21 | 3.12 |
| c | 27 | 1 | Purch. | 100 | 0.95 | 127 | (27*1 + 100*0.95)/127 | 0.96 |
| c | 27 | 1 | Purch. | 3 | 1.1 | 130 | (127*0.96 + 3*1.1)/130 | 0.96 |

How would you do it using Pandas? I've tried to use a groupby and a cumsum, but I don't know how to introduce the "if" statement. After that, I want to summarize the information and just get the `Product ID` along with the final `Stock` and `WAC`, just like this:

| Product ID | Current stock | WAC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 8 | 21.13 |
| b | 21 | 3.12 |
| c | 130 | 0.96 |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how big is your data ?

Comment: @Ben.T the dataframe has 265k rows and 25 columns

Comment: @mozway Could you maybe have a look at this question ? I can't get it solved without iterrating through the df (like the accepted answer) but I have a feeling there must be a way. Would be really nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a function and call it using `apply` in a `groupby` dataframe.

I would try something like this

```
def calc_wac(df_):
  df_ = df_.copy()
  cs_wac = 0
  for counter, row in enumerate(df_.iterrows()):
    idx,row = row
    if counter==0:
      if row['Reference'] == 'Purch.':
        cs_wac += row['Initial stock'] * row['Initial unit cost'] + row['Quantity'] * row['Unit cost']
      else:
        cs_wac += row['Current stock'] * row['Initial unit cost']
    elif row['Reference'] == 'Purch.':
      cs_wac += row['Quantity'] * row['Unit cost']
    else:
      cs_wac *= row['Current stock']/df.loc[idx-1,'Current stock']
    df_.loc[idx, 'WAC'] = cs_wac/row['Current stock']
  return pd.Series({'Current stock': row['Current stock'], 'WAC':cs_wac/row['Current stock']})
```

This should return the summarized information when you call:

`df.groupby('Product ID').apply(calc_wac)`

If you want the full dataframe just change the function return to the entire dataframe `return df_`

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your question correct.

Code:

```
#Create new columns using lambda function
df['(how to)WAC']= df.apply(lambda row: (row['Intial stock']*row['Intial unit cost']+row['Quantity']*row['Unit cost'])/row['Current stock'] if row['Reference']=='Purch' else None, axis=1)



#Creating another column WAC, here it will gonna take data from '(how to)WAC' column.
#More, if its None will will take the above value. and if its the first value then it will take from Initial 

df['WAC']  = df.groupby(['Product ID'])['(how to) WAC'].ffill().fillna(df['Initial unit cost'])




#Group by the ID and display the last rows of each
df.groupby('Product ID').tail(1)[['Product ID','Current stock', 'WAC']]#
```

Comment: your calculations don't seem to be correct. You don't include the condition that only the first row of each group will be calculated with the `initial unit cost`, all other rows take the value of `Unit cost` of the previous row.

Comment: Yes, you were right. cheers!

Comment: As @Rabinzel says, the columns `Initial stock` and `Initial unit stock` only have to be used for the first row of every product. If we use a cumsum we could avoid referencing the previous row (i-1) for the stock, but I don't know how to do it for the previous WAC. @R. Baraiya I tried your solution but it gave me a `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: Hi @cmoreno98  please specify on which you have received Error.

Comment: You are receiving that, might because somewhere in you table you are having `Current stock` as 0.